# Problema com o RSS_feed description em um custom post

Tags: wordpress, rss, custom-post-types, feed

Estou com o seguinte problema:
Tenho um custom post que possui alguns social buttons (curta, compartilhe)... Como o custom post não aparece por padrão no feed, estou usando a seguinte função:

```js
function add_events_to_rss_feed( $args ) {
if ( isset( $args['feed'] ) && !isset( $args['post_type'] ) )
$args['post_type'] = array('post', 'tribe_events');
return $args;
}
```

O problema é que o feed pega esses social buttons e joga na minha newsletter(mailchimp)... ficando assim

```html
<description><![CDATA[Facebook Twitter Google+ A partir daqui que quero que comece [..]!> </description>
```

Alguém teria uma solução pra esse problema?

Comment: Os botões estão dentro do conteúdo de cada post? Tipo com shortcodes?